# Sum of multiple columns based on condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to sum up an array of columns per row based on a condition.
I found a way to do it but it does not seem like a good idea when I have 20+ columns to sum up since it would generate an additional column for each one.

Wanted result is: Sum of values for all columns that end with "_val" where value is either 0 or 1 (or <2, i just want to exclude the value 3 right now)

```
 val df1 = Seq(
  ("id1", 1, 0, 3),
  ("id2", 0, 0, 3),
  ("id3", 1, 1, 3))
  .toDF("id", "bla_val", "blub_val", "bli_val")
```

My solution with the wanted result in the column sum

```
val channelNames = df1.schema.fieldNames.filter(_.endsWith("_val"))
val ch = channelNames.map(x => col(x+"_redval"))

val df2 = df1.select(col("*") +: (channelNames.map(c =>
  when(col(c) === 1, lit(1))
    .otherwise(lit(0)).as(c+"_redval"))): _*) 

val df3 = df2.withColumn("sum", ch.reduce(_+_))
df3.show()
```

Example output:

`+---+-------+--------+-------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---+
| id|bla_val|blub_val|bli_val|bla_val_redval|blub_val_redval|bli_val_redval|sum|
+---+-------+--------+-------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---+
|id1|      1|       0|      3|             1|              0|             0|  1|
|id2|      0|       0|      3|             0|              0|             0|  0|
|id3|      1|       1|      3|             1|              1|             0|  2|
+---+-------+--------+-------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---+`

Comment: if you want to do it dynamically, then what you have now is correct.. dont worry abt additional columns.. it lets you manipulate easily.. you can drop those columns later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the expression using reduce() operation. Check this out:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("id1", 1, 0, 3),
  ("id2", 0, 0, 3),
  ("id3", 1, 1, 3))
  .toDF("id", "bla_val", "blub_val", "bli_val")

val newcols= df1.columns.filter(_.endsWith("_val")).map( x=> when(col(x)===1, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).reduce(_+_)
df1.withColumn("redval_count",newcols).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+--------+-------+------------+
|id |bla_val|blub_val|bli_val|redval_count|
+---+-------+--------+-------+------------+
|id1|1      |0       |3      |1           |
|id2|0      |0       |3      |0           |
|id3|1      |1       |3      |2           |
+---+-------+--------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. tested your code right now and it worked like a charm.  
One little question: newcols is of datatype column. From my understanding this is something like a dataframe with a single column containing the reduced values. How does spark now to which entry of the dataframe a entry of the "column"(newcols) has to be appended?

Comment: It is not a dataframe.. just expression of columns.. we can use it for any dataframe that has those columns..

Answer (score -1):

```
def sumNot3(s: Seq[Int]): Int = {
  s.filter(_ != 3).sum
}

val sumNot3Udf = udf(sumNot3(_: Seq[Int]))

val channelNameCols = df1.schema.fieldNames.filter(_.endsWith("_val")).map(c => col(c))

df1.select(sumNot3Udf(array(channelNameCols: _*)).as("sum"))
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21456992)